# Square Root Simplifying and Solving the problem to X

Tags: roots

$e^y = \frac{x}{a} + \sqrt{( 1 + (\frac{x}{a})^2}$

The problem asks to solve this equation to x. My problem stands still by the square root.

Comment: Do you mean $$e^{y}=\frac{x}{a}+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2}$$?

Comment: Hint: $(\sqrt{1+u^2} + u)(\sqrt{1 + u^2} - u) = 1$

Comment: Well in general if you have $M = cx + \sqrt{a +  dx^2}$ you can do $M-cx =\sqrt {a + dx^2}$ and $(M-cx)^2 = a+dx^2$ and now it's just a quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

If so we write $$e^y-\frac{x}{a}=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2}$$ squaring we get
$$e^{2y}+\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2-2e^y\times \frac{x}{a}=1+\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2$$
Combining like terms and isolating $x$ we get
$$x=a\times \left(\frac{e^{2y}-1}{2e^y}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for precious time Dr.Graubner

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- $\operatorname{arsinh} t = \ln\left(t+\sqrt{1+t^2}\right)$

Setting $t = \frac{x}{a}$, your equation becomes
$$e^y = t+\sqrt{1+t^2} \Leftrightarrow y = \operatorname{arsinh} t$$

Hence,

$$t = \frac{x}{a} = \sinh y \Leftrightarrow \boxed{x= a\sinh y = a\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you for precious your time and the arcsine transformation notation.